# How can Android ART garbage collect?

Tags: android, compiler-construction, virtual-machine

As far as I am concerned, every virtual machine which processes bytecode, let's take JVM as an example, implements their own garbage collector as somehow analyzing the current state of the VM (which is executing the bytecode) and making decisions regarding collecting objects from the heap. Now, I am totally confused when it comes to ahead of time compilation. That would mean that the whole bytecode gets compiled into native code before first launching an app. So...when the app is launched, the processor executes the native code and that's that. Now, where does the VM come in if we have the whole bytecode compiled to native anyhow? Where does the GC come in, and what does it analyze? 
My whole knowledge might be completely flawed, if that is the case, please recommend me some good articles because I have read A LOT and I can't figure this out... I am going crazy!

Comment: Have you watched the ART related Google IO videos on YouTube?: https://youtu.be/EBlTzQsUoOw and https://youtu.be/fwMM6g7wpQ8

Comment: More reading: [Garbage collection with LLVM](http://llvm.org/docs/GarbageCollection.html)

Comment: @rici isn't LLVM GC a framework and not an implementation?

Comment: @FrankC: My only claim is that the page makes for interesting reading, particularly since it is oriented towards compiled languages ("ahead of time", in case that makes a difference.)

Comment: The only difference between ART and Dalvik is the way the binary is executed. For Dalvik, the binary is pure data and is executed by the DVM (libdvm.so). For ART, the binary is an executable which contains pre-compile Dalvik code (Classes, Methods, Instructions..). It is then linked with libart.so to execute the Dalvik code.

Comment: The Java GC in ART still works the same way as it does in Dalvik.

Comment: Morrison Chang, I have watched it and unfortunately it hasn't helped me..

Answer (score 0):

ART performs the translation of the application's bytecode into native instructions that are later executed by the device's runtime environment.
Runtime environment has it's own garbage collector. If you app need some memory, it will be requested from Runtime environment, not from Android OS.

You can think that your App has build in virtual machine. This virtual machine is a runtime environment.

P.S. Did you watch [Google presentation about ART](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EBlTzQsUoOw)?

[image]

Comment: So, the runtime "runs" the code which came from the ahead of time compilation i.e. native code, and the gc is part of this specific runtime? I did watch the video, some interesting information but it did not answer my question :(

Comment: Yes, it is what I want to say. GC is a part of runtime. It is normal design. For example go language has GC and it generates binary. This binary will have build in GC.